# C program launch argument

Tags: c

I want to put arguments to launch the program
For exemple : `./program -i inputfile -e -b`.
I have done the code bellow but I have a problem the argument needs an option for exemple it works when I put `-i inputfile` but if I put `-e -b` it will take the -b as an option for the `-e`.
I haven't found a solution to this as it asks me to enter an option for each argument

Thank you if you can help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define OPTSTR "h:b:c:d:e:f:i:l:g:o:r:x:s:Z:z"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, OPTSTR)) != EOF) {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'h':
                printf("AIDE POUR LE PROGRAMME");
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("-b ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("-c ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'd':
                printf("-d ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'e':
                printf("-e ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'f':
                printf("-f ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'i':
                printf("-i ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'l':
                printf("-l ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'g':
                printf("-g ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'o':
                printf("-o ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'r':
                printf("-r ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'x':
                printf("-x ENTERED");
                break;
            case 's':
                printf("-s ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'Z':
                printf("-Z ENTERED");
                break;
            case 'z':
                printf("-z ENTERED");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Mauvais argument entré ! \n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `-e` doesn't need an argument, then don't put a colon after `e` in `OPTSTR`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your option string, a letter followed by a `:` means that option expects an argument.  If an option does not take an argument, don't put `:` after it.

```
#define OPTSTR "h:b:c:d:ef:i:l:g:o:r:x:s:Z:z"
//                       ^-- no colon after "e"
```

Comment: Oh that was that simple ! Thank you so much !